# blank between data not in the end can be parsed into NA?

Tags: r

There is a data file in `c:/workspace/test.txt`  (not a fixed width formatted data file).

```
           24.9444 24.7500 24.5555 24.3389 24.0389 23.7667  NA    
24.7500 25.0167          25.6800 26.3055 24  26.1833 25      
25.5778 25.6000 25.5167 25.3944 25.1889 24.9389 24.6778 24.3833 24.0944 23.8    
25.5778 25.6000 25.5167
```

I read it ,and get the result .

```
> read.table("c:/workspace/test.txt",blank.lines.skip=FALSE, col.names=paste("x",1:10,sep=""),sep="") ->xx    
> xx    
       x1      x2      x3      x4      x5      x6      x7      x8      x9  x10
1 24.9444 24.7500 24.5555 24.3389 24.0389 23.7667      NA      NA      NA   NA
2 24.7500 25.0167 25.6800 26.3055 24.0000 26.1833 25.0000      NA      NA   NA
3 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167 25.3944 25.1889 24.9389 24.6778 24.3833 24.0944 23.8
4 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
```

Can i make the data file to be parsed as the under?

```
         x1      x2      x3      x4      x5      x6      x7      x8    x9  x10
1 NA      24.9444 24.7500 24.5555 24.3389 24.0389 23.7667      NA      NA   NA 
2 24.7500 25.0167 NA      25.6800 26.3055 24.0000 26.1833 25.0000      NA   NA
3 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167 25.3944 25.1889 24.9389 24.6778 24.3833 24.0944 23.8
4 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This substitutes NA where a sequence of 7 blanks are found, then reads it in normally:

```
 txt <- 
"           24.9444 24.7500 24.5555 24.3389 24.0389 23.7667  NA    
 24.7500 25.0167          25.6800 26.3055 24  26.1833 25      
 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167 25.3944 25.1889 24.9389 24.6778 24.3833 24.0944 23.8    
 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167         "
 ttt <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
 read.table( text = gsub("\\s{7}", " NA ", ttt) ,fill =TRUE)

       V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8
1      NA 24.9444 24.7500 24.5555 24.3389 24.0389 23.7667      NA
2 24.7500 25.0167      NA 25.6800 26.3055 24.0000 26.1833 25.0000
3 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167 25.3944 25.1889 24.9389 24.6778 24.3833
4 25.5778 25.6000 25.5167      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
       V9  V10
1      NA   NA
2      NA   NA
3 24.0944 23.8
4      NA   NA
```